# resume animation css3 from start

Tags: javascript, css, animation

i trying to make a button that stop a css3 animation and start it again
i tried the function 
`object.style.animationPlayState="paused";`

but the problem that i wanna to stop and rerun it again from the start not to resume it from the last place.

also i tried to manipulate `object.style.left` value before stop also starts from the last place it was.

my last try was setting the count with 0 but no luck so far

any ideas about this problem?

the code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Move 3 pic's</title> 
</head> 
<style>

#div1{position: relative; top:100px;}
#div2{position: relative ; top:100px;left:290px;}
#div3{position: relative ; top:250px; left:50px;}


#divmain
{
    width: 400px; height:300px; border: 10px solid navy; margin: 5px;

}

.animate1
{
animation: movingdiv1 5s infinite alternate;
animation-timing-function:linear;
}

.animate2
{
animation: movingdiv2 5s infinite alternate;
animation-timing-function:linear;
}   

.animate3
{
animation: movingdiv3 5s infinite alternate;
animation-timing-function:linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes movingdiv1 
{
from {left: 0px;}
to {left: 300px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes movingdiv2 
{
from {left: 300px;}
to {left: 0px;}
}

@-moz-keyframes movingdiv3 
{
from {top: 240px;}
to {top: 0px;}
}
</style>    
<script>
var x=0;
function start()
{
    document.getElementById("div1").style.animationIterationCount="infinite";
    document.getElementById("div2").style.animationIterationCount="infinite";
    document.getElementById("div3").style.animationIterationCount="infinite";
    if(x==1)
        {
        document.getElementById("start").value="Stop";
        document.getElementById("div1").style.animationPlayState="running";
        document.getElementById("div2").style.animationPlayState="running";
        document.getElementById("div3").style.animationPlayState="running";
        x=0;
        }
    else
        {
        document.getElementById("start").value="Start";
        document.getElementById("div1").style.animationPlayState="paused";
        document.getElementById("div2").style.animationPlayState="paused";
        document.getElementById("div3").style.animationPlayState="paused";
        x=1;
        }   
}


function reset()
{

        /*what i tried here*/
        document.getElementById("div1").style.animationPlayState="paused";
        document.getElementById("div2").style.animationPlayState="paused";
        document.getElementById("div3").style.animationPlayState="paused";

        document.getElementById("div1").style.left="0px";
        document.getElementById("div2").style.left="297px";
        document.getElementById("div3").style.top="250px";

        document.getElementById("div1").style.animationIterationCount="0";
        document.getElementById("div2").style.animationIterationCount="0";
        document.getElementById("div3").style.animationIterationCount="0";
}
</script>
<body>
<div id=divmain>
<span class="animate1" id=div1>
<img src="icon1.gif" id="icon1" width="50" height="50"/></span>
<span class="animate2" id=div2>
<img src="icon2.gif" id="icon2" width="50" height="50"/></span>
<span class="animate3" id=div3><img src="top.jpg" id="icon3" width="50" height="50"/></span>
</div>
<input id=start type=button onClick=start() value='Stop'>
<input id=reset type=button onClick=reset() value='Reset'>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rerun the animation from the start, remove the 'alternate' in the animation property.

```
.animate1
{
animation: movingdiv1 5s infinite;
animation-timing-function:linear;
}

.animate2
{
animation: movingdiv2 5s infinite;
animation-timing-function:linear;
}   

.animate3
{
animation: movingdiv3 5s infinite;
animation-timing-function:linear;
}
```

EDIT:

Maybe I didn't understand your question earlier. You want to  stop and rerun it again from the start, whenever the button is clicked. For that, I have modified the start function(). Whenever the Stop button is pressed the animate classes are removed from the moving divs. And when the start button is pressed, the animate classes are added.

```
 function start()
 {
 document.getElementById("div1").style.animationIterationCount="infinite";
document.getElementById("div2").style.animationIterationCount="infinite";
document.getElementById("div3").style.animationIterationCount="infinite";
if(x==1)
    {
    document.getElementById("start").value="Stop";
    document.getElementById("div1").className = "animate1";
    document.getElementById("div2").className = "animate2";
    document.getElementById("div3").className = "animate3";
    x=0;
    }
else
    {
    document.getElementById("start").value="Start";
    document.getElementById("div1").className = "";
    document.getElementById("div2").className = "";
    document.getElementById("div3").className = "";
    x=1;
    }   
 }
```